# What is the cause of the discrepancy in my Suggested Edits reviewer stats?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, review-stats

I have reviewed 950 suggested edits, but when I expanded the Reviewer Stats on an edit I reviewed, I see that I've approved 524 edits and rejected 326 - a total of **8**50, not **9**50.

Is it possible that I've had 100 audits? What could cause this discrepancy?

> [image]

Comment: Not sure if/how "improve" actions are accounted. Could be part of it.

Comment: @Mat That's a good point; that's what I'm looking to clarify.

Comment: If you happen to approve/reject many edits made to bad posts that gets deleted eventually it might explain it as well as the number on top is what counts towards badges and this isn't affected by deleted posts.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Another good point!

Comment: On second thought, it's probably both what @Mat said and what I said. Improve is still counted as review action **even if it was just an edit** i.e. even if the suggestion was rejected or approved by the time you confirmed the "improve" action, but in those cases it's neither approval nor rejection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's audits. But the delta seems to be from suggested edits you chose to improve, regardless of whether you marked them as helpful or not.

This matches my stats here on meta, and on DBA.SE, and I don't believe review auditing is active on either of these sites.

Comment: This is correct. Improving an edit records an **Edit** action in your history, which does not count towards either of those totals. The Community user is the one actually approving or rejecting the edit, which is also why neither of your totals increment there. It's not that the numbers don't add up, just that you're missing the third number.