# Reviewer Stats shows incorrect number of Suggested Edit rejections

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I have reviewed 1786 Suggested Edits on Super User, as shown on
the [global Review Stats](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) page:

[image]

If I go to the approval/rejection status page for a suggested edit
immediately after casting my approve/reject vote (before anybody else has voted)
and click on “(more)”, I see something like:

[image]

showing that I have approved 919 edit suggestions
and rejected 585 edit suggestions.  This sounds about right,
although the numbers add up to far less than the 1786 total. 
(OK, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182685/what-is-the-cause-of-the-discrepancy-in-my-suggested-edits-reviewer-stats)
suggests that “Improve” actions count as reviews,
but do not contribute to either the “Approve” or “Reject” counts.) 
And these numbers are updating; yesterday they were 913 and 583. 
But, if I look again after the edit has gotten its final vote, I see

[image]

(“Scott has approved 919 edit suggestions and rejected 7 edit suggestions”),
which is clearly, grossly wrong.

Note that the above two screenshots came from [the same page](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/345725), about an hour apart.

Here’s [another one](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/345730):

[image]

(and later)

[image]

Even though I rejected a suggested edit today,
the “7” is not incrementing; it was “7” yesterday.

And, BTW, the rejection numbers for
[slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck?tab=activity&sort=reviews)
and [random](https://superuser.com/users/307/random?tab=activity&sort=reviews)
are clearly wrong, too; they are among Super User’s most prolific contributors.

Comment: @rene and others: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." I'll concede that [Incorrect suggested edit review count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243910/195817) is essentially the same question as mine (although I believe that mine is better researched and better presented), but that other question ***does not*** have an answer.

Comment: It's a bit after-the-fact, @Scott, but we finally have an answer to why it happens, and it is fixed for the next build on all sites

Comment: @ChrisForrence: (1) Hooray!  (2) Thanks for the individualized notification.  (3) This is a bit odd.  It seems to have been working somewhat better for the past several months.  (Or are you saying that “Improve” actions will now count as “Approves” or “Rejects”, so the total will be right?)

Comment: No problem; I had noticed that you had asked a duplicate of mine  :) If I read the answer correctly, Improve will not count towards the approval count, while Reject and Edit will count towards the rejection count. I just asked a question to the developer who made the fix to clarify that bit.